# How to replace tag with it's value within text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I extract

> I love Python

from given HTML

```
I <img src="image.png" alt="love"> Python
```

Getting string and splitting it won't work, text is controlled by user and might contain <>

Comment: looks like you're on the right track with using beautifulsoup.  What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Is it contained in some tag for e.g div with a class attribute to distinguish it from other elements?https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: do _not_ use regular expresions to attempt to parse and modify xml ( html is a subset), @ikreb.  There's no regular expression that can accomodate all possible values within the html and all possible syntaxes.

Comment: it's contained in div, i'm using find('div', {'class': 'comment'}) to find the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to achieve that. One way to do that would be to find all `img` elements and [replace them](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) with a text node containing the `alt` value of the `img` element:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """<div class="commentthread_comment_text">I <img src="image.png" alt="love"> Python</div>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'commentthread_comment_text'})

In [5]: for img in div('img'):
    ...:     img.replace_with(img['alt'])
    ...:     

In [6]: div.get_text()
Out[6]: 'I love Python'
```